# Iframe is breaking the browser's back button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm currently loading an iframe into a webpage. This iframe's `src` gets set dynamically. The iframe loads perfectly fine. However, when the back button of the browser is pressed, the page literally just reloads. It doesn't go back to the page the user navigated from. This iframe is cross-domain. Not sure if this is due to security. Can I even do anything? Seems like this might be controlled by the iframe. Any answers would be appreciated! Just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: My suspicion would be that the page you're iframing relies on session/cookie data, which isn't being saved because of third-party cookie restrictions. Hard to say without an example of the behavior, though.

Comment: One of the reasons why Ajax was invented. Iframe has always had this problem